# Function call causes an infinite recursion

Tags: swift, struct, protocols

I am struggling how to conform to a protocol in an extension of a struct. Here's my code:

```
public protocol Foo {
    var index: Int { get set }
}

struct Bar {
    // ...
}

extension Bar: Foo {
    public var index: Int {
        get {
            return 0
        }
        set {
            self.index = newValue <== warning
        }
    }
}
```

I get this warning:

> Function call causes an infinite recursion

How can I solve this?

Comment: Setting aside the issue of why you would want to do this, you could just have a blank setter. Or, set another private variable like _index

Comment: Why is your getter returning 0? Doing so means there is no point to the property. Setting the value will always effectively be ignored since reading the value will always return 0.

Comment: Good point. I did that because I got an 'Attempting to access 'index' within its own getter` warning.   I need to rethink this.

Comment: You can't add a stored property in an extension. If you want a stored property named `index` in `Bar` then you need to add it in the original struct. Then you can indicate that `Bar` conforms to `Foo` in an extension but it would be an otherwise empty extension.

Comment: @jnpdx You can't add `_index` as a stored property in the extension so that won't work either.

Comment: @HangarRash Yes, indeed -- I would've put it in the `struct` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is that an extension can't declare a stored property. If you attempt to add a property to a struct extension, it would need to be a computed property (which is what you have attempted in your question's code. The problem with the computed property is you don't have anywhere good to store the set value.

The simplest solution is to add `index` directly to the `Bar` struct. Then you can either directly conform to `Foo` or you can add the extension to conform to `Foo`.

Option 1:

```swift
struct Bar: Foo {
    var index: Int
}
```

Option 2:

```swift
struct Bar {
    var index: Int
}

extension Bar: Foo {} // This works because Bar already has index
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it is the correct answer, so accepted.